# How to display 2 input fields one below the other?

Tags: html, angular-material

My input fields are displayed next to each other. How can I make them display below each other?

```
<div class="register-area">
  <h1>Register</h1>
  <form action="" class="register-form">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxFlex.lt-md="column" fxFlexAlign="space-around center">
      <div fxFlex="50" fxFlexOffset="25" class="wrapper">
        <mat-grid-list cols="2">
          <mat-grid-tile class="content">
            <ul>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
              <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
            </ul>
          </mat-grid-tile>
          <mat-grid-tile style="background-color: red">

            <label><input type="text" matInput placeholder="E-Mail"></label>

            <label><input type="password" matInput placeholder="Password"></label>                

          </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-responsive-grid-list-v2-zzquxz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `<figure>` that is part of `mat-grid-tile` component, set `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column;`

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping your input in a div

```
<div style="display: grid">
<input1...>
<input2...>
</div>
```

Comment: What about browser compatibility? I don't think that each browser supports grid.

Answer (score 0):

Input and label elements are by default [inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements), and unlike [block elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) they only occupy the space bounded by their content.

To solve your issue you can do any of the following:

- Add a `<br/>` element after your input

```
...
<label><input type="text" matInput placeholder="E-Mail"></label> <br/>
<label><input type="password" matInput placeholder="Password"></label> 
...
```

- Wrap your input elements inside any block element, the most common is `div`

```
...
<div>
<label><input type="text" matInput placeholder="E-Mail"></label>
</div>
<div>
<label><input type="password" matInput placeholder="Password"></label>
</div>
...
```

- Transform your inline elements to block elements using CSS

```
...
<label style="display:block"><input type="text" matInput placeholder="E-Mail"></label>
<label style="display:block"><input type="password" matInput placeholder="Password"></label>
...
```

you can read more about inline and block elements in the links above, I think understanding the differences can help you build layouts more easily.